# how to find the last executed command status in foreach loop in perl

Tags: bash, perl, unix, sh

I have a piece of logic it will execute the start service one by one based on the list of servers now question is after successful execution of **last server** I need to do some action based on status. how to handle the command to wait until the last sever to perform

Kindly suggest

sample code.

```
    foreach my $Server_name(@servers)
    {
     my $command =qq(sudo /bin/su - jenkins -c "ssh scm\@$Server_name ' /bin/sh ${SCRIPT_HOME}/startService.sh'");
    print "$command\n";
    system($command);
            if ($?== 0)
            {
             do some action

             }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that "_do some action_" needs to wait? So that the action is done after the `foreach` loop ... ?

Comment: yes "do some action" need to wait and execute based on status of last executed command in foreach loop. @zdim

Comment: Then just do it after the `foreach`.  For every iteration save the status in a variable (declared before the loop so that it exists after it), so after the loop the variable will have the status of the last command.  Is that what you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`$?` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$?) in this case contains the status of `system`, but [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) itself returns that as well. Then assign its return to a variable and check it after the loop

```
my $exit_status;
foreach my $server_name (@servers)
{
     my $command = qq(sudo /bin/su - jenkins -c "ssh scm\@$server_name ' /bin/sh ${SCRIPT_HOME}/startService.sh'");
     print "$command\n";
     $exit_status = system($command);
}

if ($exit_status == 0) { ... }
```

I'd like to also comment

- We don't know what you need from errors but consider  whether `$?` is enough; if you only check *for* errors it's fine but otherwise all you get from `system` is the last `wait` call's status. Various `IPC` modules provide for better error reporting
- A  command in a string for `system` can be unsafe as it may get passed to the shell to interpret first. If the shell isn't actually needed it is better to use the LIST form of [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), where the shell isn't involved; also see [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) for discussion of the LIST form
- To prepare a string for the command it is better to use [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm)